# Swift Encodable: encode nil as an empty object

Tags: json, swift, codable, foundation, encodable

How can I encode a nil property as an empty JSON object?

```
struct Foo: Encodable {
    let id = 10
    let bar: Bar? = nil
}

struct Bar: Encodable {
    let number: Int
}

let data = try! JSONEncoder().encode(Foo())

print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!)
```

This prints out:

`"{"id":7}"`

What I want is:

`"{"id":7, "bar":{}}"`

Comment: This would basically break the symmetry between encoding and decoding, wondering what's the use case that would demand such an encoding.

Comment: `let bar: Bar? = nil` this is pointless. bar will always be `nil`

Comment: Wouldn't be better to encode NSNull instead ?

Comment: @LeoDabus this code is just to showcase my problem.

Comment: @Cristik the API I'm using requires that I do so. I agree that it's not conventional, but I don't have a choice. And I'm only encoding it, never decoding it from JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you'd need this, as encoding to a form that fails decoding is not something usually done.

Nonetheless, if you find yourself needing this kind of logic in multiple places, you can extend `KeyedEncodingContainer` with this kind of functionality:

```swift
extension KeyedEncodingContainer {
    mutating func encodeOptional<T: Encodable>(_ value: T?, forKey key: Self.Key) throws {
        if let value = value { try encode(value, forKey: key) }
        else { try encode([String:String](), forKey: key) }
    }
}
```

, and then implement the `encode(to:)` method in `Foo`:

```swift
struct Foo: Encodable {
    let id = 10
    let bar: Bar? = nil
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case bar
    }
    
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(id, forKey: .id)
        try container.encodeOptional(bar, forKey: .bar)
    }
}
```

You can also extend `UnkeyedDecodingContainer`, and `SingleValueDecodingContainer` with similar `encodeOptional` methods, if you find yourself needing to encode empty JSON objects for nil values in other kind of containers.

Comment: This looks very clean! The only reason I need this is because the API I'm using requires that I do so...

Answer (score 3):

You can introduce an empty struct with no properties to the `encoder`, when `bar = nil`

```
struct Foo: Encodable {
    let id = 10
    let bar: Bar? = nil
    
    enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case bar
    }
    
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(id, forKey: .id)
        
        if let bar = bar {
            try container.encode(bar, forKey: .bar)
        }
        else {
            try container.encode(Empty(), forKey: .bar)
        }
    }
}

struct Bar: Encodable {
    let number: Int
}

struct Empty: Encodable {
}
```

Comment: You got there before me. LOL! Was just typing out an answer pretty much exactly as this too. 

Comment: @Fogmeister I guess I was few seconds quicker to post the answer then :)

Answer (score 2):

Implement a custom `encode(to:)` for `Foo` and use an empty dictionary if `Bar` is nil

```
struct Foo: Encodable {
    let id = 10
    let bar: Bar? = nil

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, bar
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(id, forKey: .id)
        switch bar {
        case .some(let value):
            try container.encode(value, forKey: .bar)
        case .none:
            try container.encode([String: Bar?](), forKey: .bar)
        }
    }
}
```